# nginx rewrite rules: Rewrite https://Frontend/backend/Api/SelectAllBranch/ to https://Backend/Api/SelectAllBranch/ or .../SelectAllBranch

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, rewrite, rules

I'm using this configuration to nginx proxy reverso

```
 location /backend {
      rewrite ^/backend(.*)$ $1/ break;
      proxy_pass http://credentials-web-bff.cl-milugar:5000;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

and i don't have problem when Url like https://frontend/backend/mysite , but when the Url finish in "/" this rule didn't work.

can you guys help me ?

Comment: Why are you adding an extra trailing `/` in your `rewrite` statement? It should probably be `rewrite ^/backend(.*)$ $1 break;`

Comment: It is an older angular application , because of that I don't have permission to change those URL on the proxy reverso. I'm only changing the pod setting

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/backend(.*?)/?$ $1/ break;`

Comment: it's work , thank you , i 'm going to test the others url